# Get payload of 400 response when consuming JSON api on JAVA

Tags: java, json, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to consume a JSON API from my java web project but I'm having a problem when the API returns a 400 Bad Request response instead of a 200 OK.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();      
WebTarget target = client.target(REST_URI_PATH+resource);
String respuesta = "";
try {
   respuesta=target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(data),String.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

I had to add the try catch block because without it the `target.request` line was exploding with an Exception saying that the status was 400. Now what I would like to do is to get the payload from the response even when it's a 400 Bad Request.

I've tried using

```
Response respuesta=target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(data));
```

and playing around with the Response object, but i got nowhere. I'm new at Java by the way haha.
Thank you and sorry for my english!

EDIT 1:

I'm consuming a login service, the server is not the problem, it returns a 400 Bad Request on purpose when the credentials are invalid.

`data` contains a JSON that looks like this

```
String data= "{"+
                "user"+":{email:"+email+","+
                "password"+":"+password +","+
                "username"+":"+name+
               "}}";
```

which is valid and works (returns 200 and i can get the payload) when the credentials are valid.

This is the stacktrace of the exception when the response is 400:

```
Stack Trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.ws.rs.BadRequestException: HTTP 400 Bad Request
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70)
io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You will see the reason for this on the webservice side. Why don't you pass parameters ? Does it support post really or only get ?

Comment: Can you show what `data` is? And also the `exception stacktrace`

Comment: Have you ever printed the value of data and checked its validity? It looks wrong

Comment: Yes, the data json is valid. It's expected to get the 400 response in this case sinceIf the credentials are valid the server responds with status 200, if they are not (this case) it responds with 400.
What I need to do it's get the JSON payload that comes with it.

Comment: Is the JSON payload data from the server or is this the data you sent? If its comes from the server it would be good to see the server side implementation.

Comment: It comes from the server, but i do not have access to it's implementation. What's the standard way to get the payload from a JSON 400 response on Java?